# In Bash, is it possible to throw an error if an SFTP connection is not established?

Tags: python, bash, sftp

I'm able to connect to an SFTP connection with a Bash script but want to account for bad connections, like there's no internet connection, the key file goes bad, etc.

Is there a way to throw an error in Bash if I have a bad connection? It seems like `SFTP` automatically denies permission if the key is bad and then closes the connection.

Would this be possible in Python?

Comment: What do you want to happen on an error? In Bash, the SFTP command will return a non-zero exit code if an error happened. You can check this immediately after the command with the Bash variable `$?`

Comment: using `paramiko` it would be possible

Comment: I'd consider using `lftp`, which (1) does in fact support sftp (and also scp, and even file transfer over a SSH connection to a POSIX-compliant shell!), and (2) likewise reports useful exit codes back to the calling shell.

Comment: ...that said, if you already have something that closes and exits, it's probably setting the exit status to a nonzero (failed) value as it is already. Can you show a demonstration showing that it isn't doing so?

Comment: @Ben I'm a bit confused; how do I check with `$`? @taesu I'm guessing that `paramiko` is only for Python right?

Comment: @simplycoding All bash commands exit with a code. A code of `0` means successful, a code of anything else was some kind of failure. The exit code of the previous command is stored in `$?`. See this for yourself - in the shell run a command that works, and then type `echo $?`. It will print `0`. Then run a command that fails (or just `false`), and type `echo $?`. It will print `1`. You can use this in scripts to know whether the previous command was successful or not.

Comment: Great, thanks. Just came across this question which also helps: http://serverfault.com/questions/380020/detecting-upload-success-failure-in-a-scripted-command-line-sftp-session

Answer (score 0):

Bash errors are pretty simple: you either exit with a return code in the middle of your script [and document it for yourself somewhere for handling it in another script], or handle the return code through if statements (as in retry your sftp command).

You could use function and specify a set of return codes to do this that way within a single script.

Python is a more full-featured language: if you use a library to do the calls (such as subprocess to make your shell commands directly, or  paramiko if you're doing commands over ssh) you can catch the errors more directly using a try/except block:

```
try:
    rc = subprocess.check_call('ssh 348.3454.342.21', shell=True) # bogus IP
except CalledProcessError, e:
    print e
```

It'll output:

```
ssh: Could not resolve hostname 348.3454.342.21: Name or service not known
CalledProcessError: Command 'ssh 348.3454.342.21' returned non-zero exit status 255
```

Paramiko will have more explicit error types for connection failures and the like. However, commands run with paramiko that fail on the remote host will not throw errors if they error out on the remote device.

```
def setup_session(server,key_filename):
    paramiko.util.log_to_file('%s_paramiko.log'%(server))
    ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
    ssh.load_system_host_keys()
    ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.
    try:
        ssh.connect(server,username='root',key_filename=key_filename)
    except BadHostKeyException, e:
        do_badhostkey_thing()
    except AuthenticationException, e:
        do_authenticationexception_thing()
    except SSHException, e:
        do_sshexception_thing()
    return ssh
```